# Key layout for only turning off the display?

Tags: screen, buttons

According to [this](https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files.html) website:

```
# This is an example of a key layout file for basic system controls,
# such as volume and power keys which are typically implemented as GPIO pins
# the device decodes into key presses.

key 114   VOLUME_DOWN
key 115   VOLUME_UP
key 116   POWER
```

`POWER` turns off the display **and** makes the phone go to sleep.  Is there a key layout for **just turning off the display** (without putting the phone to sleep)? If not, can I create one?

Comment: Yes, kinda. It is ran in a terminal/adb (root needed for the former, but not for the latter) in a terminal, run 'input keyevent 26' in adb, run 'adb shell input key event 26' (no ' marks for either)

Comment: @DanB This puts the phone to sleep (locks the device). As I said, I need a key layout for just turning off the display (without putting the phone to sleep).

Comment: @TheGameChanger What behaviour are you trying to get? Are you trying to turn off the screen without causing the lock screen to appear when you next turn the screen on?

Comment: If what @Josh said is what is what you mean, try setting up a tasker profile to display a black screen

Comment: @Josh No. When I press a button, I'd like to **only**  turn off the display without putting the phone to sleep

Comment: @DanB That's not what I mean. Read my reply above :) Did you guys understand?

Comment: @TheGameChanger yes, we do understand. However,  its not possible, short of an entire ROM/ Kernel rewrite to support your feature.

Comment: @DanB Can you please explain further?

Comment: @TheGameChanger I'll try :). Turning off the screen without putting it to sleep is not available within android (yet) Doze was not a feature until android 6, and samsungs ultra power saving mode was not badass until 5.0. Why? The kernel, hardware and ROM were set up to suppprt it all. Doze effectively dropped the cpu clock speed to almost zero. In your case, the hardware would probably accept it, bit you would need to write the system and kernel to accept your idea. Asking how to do that though, is for another site (stack overflow, perhaps?)

Comment: @DanB Thanks for your wonderful reply. Can you provide any sources regarding the unavailability of "turning off the screen without putting it to sleep" within Android?

Comment: @TheGameChanger not really, since it has not been an issue to arise before. You lock your device, you forget about the implications,  often because they dont exist.

Comment: @TheGameChanger Besides, At one point, these sources had no sources. New sources have to be made for new things. If that was understandable ;)

Comment: @DanB I understand.